# Are color laser printers good enough to print photos?

Tags: printing, photos, colors, laser-printer

Are color laser printers good enough to print photos? Or they too expensive and produces low quality photos?

Comment: For consumer or professional level? For how much printing?

Comment: To print a lot of photo at home.

Comment: Let's say 300 per month.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Laser printers are great for speed and "business graphics" (think pie charts). For the rich color and glossy finish of photos you'll want an ink-based solution. When compared side-by-side the ink/bubblejet print will beat out the laser print every time.

For the best results try  for a 4-color process (separate Cyan, Magenta, Yellow and Black cartridges) printer with a native resolution over 1440 dpi.

I've had decent luck with Epsons and HPs. I have heard good things about Canons but have not owned one myself.

Comment: I'm still waiting for a good "hybrid": laser for most prints and some of the black coloring of the photo, ink for full color and photos.

Comment: @Joel - Lasers do produce a stunning black. I had to print brochures with a color photo on the front off a laser and while it looked decent, printing the same brochure on an ink jet made the colors more lifelike. But damn the text look good on the laser version. A hybrid would rock.

Comment: @RobAllen Are you saying besides black and white printing, inkjets pwn lasers? (quality)

Comment: @Pacerier - Not exactly. It isn't that simple. When consumer and business lasers lay down a bunch of toner in a small space (like a photo) it has a thick matte finish to it, so color photos lose their shine, clarity and color definition. If you are producing a block of a single color like the charts I mentioned, or a logo, or other color application that doesn't have the complexity of a photo, Laser is hard to beat. You also have other factors in Laser's favor like speed and efficiency

Answer (score 2):

Did you buy a printer yet?  You might look into the dye-sub printers.  There are several for making 6x4in prints.  The output is indistinguishable from photographic, though the color does not pop quite as much.  For larger prints, the Phaser line of printers are decent, though pricey.

**Edit:**
I do not wish to promote any particular 6x4in printer model, but Google does list such printers with the search term `dye sub photo printer` .

Xerox has a list of Phaser dye sub printers [here](http://www.office.xerox.com/solid-ink/enus.html), along with a sales blurb on the benefits of solid ink.  The Phasers can easily handle a 100 prints a day.  [Kodak](http://www.kodak.com/global/en/professional/products/printers/dyeSub/thermalPrinters.jhtml?pq-path=13318/13336) also has some interesting printers, though I've never used them or seen their output.

Comment: Any link for concrete model?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've found, no they are not good enough for decent photo prints.  If you want to print at home, I would suggest the [Epson PictureMate](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000UMRWCC).  It only does 4x6 printing, but the quality/value ratio is quite good.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to invest in a laser printer (more than $500), it can produce decent prints, and last longer.

Before you buy, pay attention to the printer's density, measured in dpi (you'll want at least 300dpi ). Also, always ask to **try** the printer.

Comment: 300 DPI will not produce good Picture quality.

Comment: 300 DPI is reasonably good for text, but you want a lot higher for photos.

Comment: There is DPI and then there is PPI.  The old fashioned prints from the film processor used approximately 300 PPI output onto photo paper.  An inkjet will need considerably more DPI than PPI due to the dithering process to produce color.